# Redirecting command output when batch file is executed by an application

Tags: java, vb.net, windows, batch-file

I have a web application that executes a batch file.

This batch file executes a java class whose output appears in the command window that ran the batch file.

The batch file is written so that any output received from the executed java class is outputted and saved to a text file on the server.

This is performed using the 'Redirecting command output (>)' as discussed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

In Windows Server 2008, this works fine.

We have upgraded our server to Windows Server 2012 and noticed that while the text file is created, the contents are empty.

When we manually click the batch file on the server, the text file has a response written to it. However when we execute the batch file from our web application, the text file is created but has no response text.

Is this a compatibility issue with Windows Server 2012, and if so is there a work around/fix?

For reference we are using a VB.NET web application which calls the batch file by creating an object with CreateObject("WScript.Shell") and then using object.Run(batchfile).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue by avoiding batch files altogether.

Instead we call the Java class file directly which fixed our problem.

Answer (score 0):

CMD.exe is the program that implements redirection for command lines. If you want cmd to provide redirection.

```
cmd /c commandline >> log.file
```

I find it strange it is created.